# Is there a design pattern to avoid this repetition or reflection?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, reflection

**Situation:**

I have some code that could be either:

- a) Poor Performance (Reflection)
- b) Repetitious
- c) Difficult(ish) to maintain

I was hoping there was a way to get maintainable non-repetitious code that didn't have the performance hit Reflection does.

**a)** One performance gouging function.

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem(this Object item, string textProperty, string valueProperty, bool isSelected)
{
    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = item.GetType().GetProperty(textProperty).GetValue(item, null),
        Value = item.GetType().GetProperty(valueProperty).GetValue(item, null)
    };
}
```

**b)** 12 functions where the code is 90% similar.

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem(this Class1 type)
{
    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = type.Name,
        Value = type.LoadInfoTypeID.ToString() // This ID is the only thing that changes.
    };
}
```

**c)** 1 Function that requires some slightly difficult to maintain coding.

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem(this Object type)
{
    int ID = type is Class1 ? (type as Class1).SomeID :
             type is Class2 ? (type as Class2).AnotherID :
             type is ClassN ? (type as ClassN).YetAnotherID :
             -1;
    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = type.Name, // Ignore the fact that Object doesn't technically have a Name Prop for the moment.
        Value = ID.ToString()
    };
}
```

**Question**:

Is there a more maintainable non-repetitious way that the code above that doesn't inhibit performance (at least not excessively)?

Situation c) is acceptable if I have to use it, but I was wondering if there were any alternatives that I wasn't aware of.

**Also**:

These Classes (Class1, Class2, etc.) are **Entities in Entity-Framework**. I'm not sure if that adds/removes any options available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have the classes in question adhere to a specific interface which allows for a generalized way of operating on the data as required.

The interface provides a contract which can be understood by future programmers for maintenance and allows a type consistent way of processing the instances outside of the reflection operations.

There appears to be a pattern which is recognized; hence using this design simply works on the existing process. A secondary interface(?) could handle the other instances, the 5%, of the other processing.

Comment: Is it possible to have classes of third-party namespaces or (in my case) Entity-Framework adhere to interfaces created by me?

Comment: Is it really 3rd party, or is it autogenerated classes by EF? If it is just the auto generated classes, those classes should be `partial` by default so you should be able to add the interface on in your own partial class in the same namespace.

Comment: For EF situations create a partial class for the target entity which adheres to the interface and if needed provides new properties which simply route to the internal properties to work with the 95% situations.

Comment: Well shoot. I guess I should have just asked about EF interfaces instead haha. That helps a lot knowing that. I just assumed it wasn't possible if you did Database-first.

Comment: @Shelby115 I have had to do the EF Partial *trick* for awhile, so you are on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options (without 3rd party libraries like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) which does this kind of stuff for you).

One would be use a interface on your classes and pass that in instead (see [OmegaMan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26344208/80274))

Another option would be use a single function that took in some delegates to decide the types to use.

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem<TItem>(this TItem type, Func<TItem, string> nameSelector, Func<Titem, string> valueSelector)
{

    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = nameSelector(type)
        Value = valueSelector(type)
    };
}

//elsewhere
Class1 item1 = ...
item1.ToSelectListItem(a=>a.Name, a=>a.SomeId);
Class2 item2 = ...
item2.ToSelectListItem(a=>a.Name, a=>a.AnotherID);
ClassN itemN = ...
itemN.ToSelectListItem(a=>a.Name, a=>a.YetAnotherID);
```

Comment: Oh snap! I completely forgot about this stuff! I use for it! Finally! I think in this case OmegaMan's answer would be best but I really appreciate this answer. I've been looking for a situation when these would be good.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a solution similar to the a) but without reflection would be sufficient? Plus, you do not have to refer to properties using string names.

```
public static SelectListItem<T>(T o, Func<T, string> textFunc, Func<T, string> valueFunc)
{
    return new SelectListItem
        {
            Selected = false,
            Text = textFunc(o),
            Value = valueFunc(o)
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

you CAN add properties, also in EF-generated code. Most templates generate partials for this purpose. So you could have:

```
public interface ITextValue
{
    string GetValue();
    string GetText();
}

// for each entity
public partial class SomeEntity : ITextValue // this for each EF-type
{
    public GetValue() { return this.ID.ToString(); }
    public GetValue() { return this.Name; }
}
```

and then

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem(this ITextValue obj)
{
    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = obj.GetText(),
        Value = obj.GetValue()
    };
}
```

If, however, you do not want to modify your EF- types you could use this approach:

```
public interface ITextValue
{
    string GetValue(object obj);
    string GetText(object obj);
}

// for each entity
public class SomeEntityReader : ITextValue // this for each EF-type
{
    public GetValue(object obj) { return ((SomeEntity).ID).ToString(); }
    public GetValue(object obj) { return ((SomeEntity)this).Name; }
}

// somewhere central
var Readers = new Dictionary<Type,ITextValue>()
Readers.Add(typeof(SomeEntity), new SomeEntityReader());
// etc
```

and then

```
static public SelectListItem ToSelectListItem(this object item)
{
    var reader = Readers(typeof(item));
    return new SelectListItem()
    {
        Selected = false,
        Text = reader.GetText(),
        Value = reader.GetValue()
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest make your classes derived from some base class which will expose some `ID` field or method `GetId` that will be overridden.

```
public abstract class YourAbstractClass 
{
    public abstract int ID { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteClass1 : YourAbstractClass
{
    public override int ID
    { 
        get { return SomeID } 
        set { SomeID = value } 
    }
}
```

In case of property you might need to decorate `ID` with `NotMappedAttribute`.